# How to solve memory leak in WPF, caused of DependencyProperty OverrideMetadata?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

I have an WPF application. I have a button, that opens modal window in it, using **ShowDialog()** for that.I found that my modal window, is cause of memory leak, it's never getting disposed, and is getting allocated a new instance each time.

After going deep in code, and using ANTS profiler, I found, that cause of the leak, was this lines below. I'm using custom Styles for my APP. When I'm removing Styles from XAML file, window is getting disposed properly.

**What is wrong in this static Constructor? it's the reason for leak.**

```
   static StyleWindow()
{
   StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(StyleWindow),new 
   FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(StyleWindow))));
} 

//StyleProperty definition
public static readonly DependencyProperty StyleProperty;
```

Thanks a lot, any help and ideas appreciated!

Comment: why do you use static ctor for this ?

Comment: If you define a dependency property `StyleProperty` in your class I wouldn't expect to see an `OverrideMetadata` on that same property. You should be able to set the metadata during registration of the dependency property.